# SwiftShield error when try to obfuscate code

Tags: ios, swift, obfuscation

I am trying to obfuscate my project using SwiftShield, but i am getting below error even if i try on SwiftShield demo project.

> error response (Request Failed): error: unknown argument:
> '-use-frontend-parseable-output' Error: Error
> Domain=com.rockbruno.swiftshield Code=0 "error response (Request
> Failed): error: unknown argument: '-use-frontend-parseable-output'"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=error response (Request Failed):
> error: unknown argument: '-use-frontend-parseable-output'} make: ***
> [swiftshield] Error 1

Please helps me how to resolve it, i am wondering that it is very popular library even if no any tutorial or any more answers found on google about it.

Thanks.

Comment: The error message seems quite clear. According to the GitHub page, there is no argument `-use-frontend-parseable-output`, but if there was it would be `--use-frontend-parseable-output`. Arguments that are more than a single letter use two dashes by convention

Comment: I am not adding any argument i am just entering the command "make shiftshield" that found on their document, if i use any other command then still it give same error. if seems issue with shiftshield installation.

Comment: I cloned the repo and typed "make" and it worked perfectly. Did you see the note on the repo - "Don't use this tool for production apps. I gave up on keeping this tool updated because every Swift release breaks SourceKit in a different way. It's probably really broken and is only useful as a way for you to learn more about obfuscation and SourceKit."

Comment: Yes, i read that "Don't use this tool for production apps".

How it works in your case? are you just downloaded repo and just fired the cmd and works fine? No need to install anything in your case like pods or copy file something ?

Comment: Nope. I did a `git clone` and then `make`. That's all.

Comment: ok, understand, i tried but in my case not works anyhow.

Comment: That argument doesn't appear in the makefile.  What repo did you clone?

Comment: git clone https://github.com/rockbruno/swiftshield.git

This i used to clone.

Comment: Yep. I did that, followed by `cd swiftshield` and `make`.